# How can I get winres.exe (.net resource editor) tool?

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, .net-3.5, windows-xp

I would like to use [Windows Forms Resource Editor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bxdx003%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) but I can't find winres.exe file in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin nor C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin folders. I searched whole disk for winres.exe file and it is not present. I have reinstalled .NET Framework 3.5 but it hasn't help.

How can I get this file?

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not present there either.

Comment: I suppose it could be missing if you use the Express edition.  Download and install the Windows SDK.

Comment: Yes, that's it. I use VS 2010 Express Edition and it doesn't install all SDK tools. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you've installed the .NET Framework SDK or just the Framework? It should be included in the Framework SDK, and once installed you can run it from command prompt just by typing `winres`.

Comment: I mean SDK. I have lots of tools in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin, like: al.exe, ResGen.exe, etc. But no winres.exe.

Comment: But it was SDK from VS 2010 Express Edition, hence missing some tools from full SDK.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Win10 with Visual Studio 2017, then open `Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017` (Win+S and type in relevant keywords) and `winres` will be accessible there without environment tweaking.